# Scrutinizer: it always install node 6.11 instead of 8.10

Tags: scrutinizer

I'm configuring the scrutinizer tools but it appears i'm doing something wrong.
In the configuration system (https://scrutinizer-ci.com/g/Rebolon/json-reviver/settings/build-config) i use this setup:

`build:
        nodes:
            analysis:
                environment:
                    redis: false
                    postgresql: false
                    node:
                        version: '8.10.0'
            tests: true
    checks:
        javascript: true`

First it appears that redis and postgresql are still installed.
Then in the log page of the last build i can see that it installed node 6.11 instead of 8.10 and that it failed when running the yanr task.

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

In your scrutinizer.yml file add:

```
build:
    environment:
        node: 10.15.3
```

Scrutinizer will only install a version higher than 6 if you specifically request it.